# Exclamation Point in Visual Studio Community 2022 Breakpoint Flag

Tags: visual-studio-2022, breakpoints

This is a trivial question.  I am seeing what looks like a small exclamation point in the breakpoint red dot when VS Community 2022 stops on one.  As I recall, VS Community 2019 merely displayed the yellow arrow over the dot.  Should I know anything about the exclamation point?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indicates that you hit the breakpoint on a different thread from what you are currently on.

Comment: Thanks.  This is prompting me to look more carefully at my threading situation.